Computing autocorrelation using FFT
The following was my original class for computing autocorrelations.
This is written in C# 4.7.0.
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace MyNameSpace
{
    public sealed class TimeSeriesAnalysis
    {
        private readonly IEnumerable<Vector3> _source;
        private int _count;

        public TimeSeriesAnalysis(IEnumerable<Vector3> vectorList)
        {
            _source = vectorList;
            _count = vectorList.Count();
        }

        public double AutoCorr(int lag)
        {
            int n = _count;

            if (n == 0 || lag >= n || lag < 0)
                throw new ArgumentException($"Lag must be between 0 and {n - 1}, and the list cannot be empty.");

            double sum = 0;

            int targetIndex = n - lag;

            for (int i = 0; i < targetIndex; i++)
            {
                var vecA = _source.Skip(i).Take(1).First();

                var vecB = _source.Skip(i + lag).Take(1).First();

                sum += vecA.Dot(vecB);
            }

            return sum / (n - lag);
        }

        public IEnumerable<double> GetCResults(int maxLag, double c0)
        {
            for (int lag = 0; lag <= maxLag; lag++)
            {
                double cValue = 0;

                try
                {
                    cValue = AutoCorr(lag);
                }
                catch (ArgumentException ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    yield break; // Exit the loop if an invalid lag is encountered
                }

                yield return cValue / c0; // Normalization is done here
            }
        }

        public PairReturn<double> GetAutoCorrelationPoints(int maxLag)
        {
            int vectorCount = _count;

            double c0 = AutoCorr(0); // This is the normalization factor

            Console.WriteLine($"Normalization factor: {c0}");

            int validMaxLag = Math.Min(maxLag, _count - 1); // Ensure maxLag does not exceed n-1

            var values = Enumerable.Range(0, validMaxLag + 1).Select(lag => (double)lag);

            return new PairReturn<double>(values, GetCResults(maxLag, c0));
        }

    }    
}

This class works well.
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using MyNameSpace;

namespace MyNameSpace____unit_test
{
    [TestClass]
    public class TimeSeriesAnalysisVec3AutoCorrelationMemoryLess____unit_test
    {

        [TestInitialize]
        public void Initialize()
        {
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void GetAutoCorrelationTestMethod()
        {
            IList<Vector3> vect3List = new List<Vector3>()
            {
                new Vector3(1,1,1),
                new Vector3(2,2,2),
                new Vector3(3,3,3),
                new Vector3(4,4,4),
                new Vector3(5,5,5)
            };

            var timeSeriesAnalysis = new TimeSeriesAnalysis(vect3List);

            double c0 = timeSeriesAnalysis.AutoCorr(0);//33
            double c1 = timeSeriesAnalysis.AutoCorr(1);//30
            double c2 = timeSeriesAnalysis.AutoCorr(2);//26
            double c3 = timeSeriesAnalysis.AutoCorr(3);//21
            double c4 = timeSeriesAnalysis.AutoCorr(4);//15

            Assert.AreEqual(33, c0);
            Assert.AreEqual(30, c1);
            Assert.AreEqual(26, c2);
            Assert.AreEqual(21, c3);
            Assert.AreEqual(15, c4);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void GetAutoCorrelationPointsTestMethod()
        {
            List<Vector3> vect3List = new List<Vector3>()
            {
                new Vector3(1,1,1),
                new Vector3(2,2,2),
                new Vector3(3,3,3),
                new Vector3(4,4,4),
                new Vector3(5,5,5)
            };

            var timeSeriesAnalysis = new TimeSeriesAnalysis(vect3List);

            var autocorr = timeSeriesAnalysis.GetAutoCorrelationPoints(10);

            IList<double> tausList = new List<double>(autocorr.XData);
            IList<double> autocorrList = new List<double>(autocorr.YData);

            Assert.AreEqual(5, tausList.Count);
            Assert.AreEqual(5, autocorrList.Count);

            Assert.AreEqual(1.0, autocorrList[0]);
            Assert.AreEqual(0.90909090909090906, autocorrList[1]);
            Assert.AreEqual(0.78787878787878785, autocorrList[2]);
            Assert.AreEqual(0.63636363636363635, autocorrList[3]);
            Assert.AreEqual(0.45454545454545453, autocorrList[4]);
        }
    }
}

Then, I had to rewrite this class using FFT (fast fourier transform).
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using MathNet.Numerics;
using MathNet.Numerics.IntegralTransforms;


namespace MyNameSpace
{
    public sealed class TimeSeriesAnalysisFFT
    {
        private readonly List<Vector3> _source;
        private int _count;

        public TimeSeriesAnalysisFFT(IEnumerable<Vector3> vectorList)
        {
            _source = vectorList.ToList();
            _count = _source.Count;
        }

        public double AutoCorr(int lag)
        {
            int n = _count;

            if (n == 0 || lag >= n || lag < 0)
                throw new ArgumentException($"Lag must be between 0 and {n - 1}, and the list cannot be empty.");

            // Using FFT to compute autocorrelation
            var realValues = _source.Select(v => v.X).ToArray();

            // Remove mean to center the data
            double mean = realValues.Average();
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                realValues[i] -= mean;
            }

            var complexValues = new Complex32[n];
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                complexValues[i] = new Complex32((float)realValues[i], 0);
            }

            // Forward FFT
            Fourier.Forward(complexValues, FourierOptions.Matlab);

            // Compute power spectrum (magnitude squared)
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                complexValues[i] = complexValues[i] * Complex32.Conjugate(complexValues[i]);
            }

            // Inverse FFT to get the autocorrelation
            Fourier.Inverse(complexValues, FourierOptions.Matlab);

            // Extract the real part and normalize by number of samples
            var autocorr = complexValues.Select(c => c.Real / n).ToArray();

            // Return the normalized value for the given lag
            double variance = realValues.Sum(x => x * x) / n;

            if (variance == 0)
                return 0;

            return autocorr[lag] / variance;
        }

        public IEnumerable<double> GetCResults(int maxLag, double c0)
        {
            for (int lag = 0; lag <= maxLag; lag++)
            {
                double cValue = 0;

                try
                {
                    cValue = AutoCorr(lag);
                }
                catch (ArgumentException ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    yield break; // Exit the loop if an invalid lag is encountered
                }

                yield return cValue / c0; // Normalization is done here
            }
        }

        public PairReturn<double> GetAutoCorrelationPoints(int maxLag)
        {
            int vectorCount = _count;

            double c0 = AutoCorr(0); // This is the normalization factor

            Console.WriteLine($"Normalization factor: {c0}");

            int validMaxLag = Math.Min(maxLag, _count - 1); // Ensure maxLag does not exceed n-1

            var values = Enumerable.Range(0, validMaxLag + 1).Select(lag => (double)lag);

            return new PairReturn<double>(values, GetCResults(maxLag, c0));
        }
    }
}

However, the following unit-test fails:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using MyNameSpace;

namespace MyNameSpace____unit_test
{
    [TestClass]
    public class TimeSeriesAnalysisFFT____unit_test
    {

        [TestInitialize]
        public void Initialize()
        {
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void GetAutoCorrelationTestMethod()
        {
            IList<Vector3> vect3List = new List<Vector3>()
            {
                new Vector3(1,1,1),
                new Vector3(2,2,2),
                new Vector3(3,3,3),
                new Vector3(4,4,4),
                new Vector3(5,5,5)
            };

            var timeSeriesAnalysis = new TimeSeriesAnalysisFFT(vect3List);

            double c0 = timeSeriesAnalysis.AutoCorr(0);//33
            double c1 = timeSeriesAnalysis.AutoCorr(1);//30
            double c2 = timeSeriesAnalysis.AutoCorr(2);//26
            double c3 = timeSeriesAnalysis.AutoCorr(3);//21
            double c4 = timeSeriesAnalysis.AutoCorr(4);//15

            Assert.AreEqual(33, c0);
            Assert.AreEqual(30, c1);
            Assert.AreEqual(26, c2);
            Assert.AreEqual(21, c3);
            Assert.AreEqual(15, c4);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void GetAutoCorrelationPointsTestMethod()
        {
            List<Vector3> vect3List = new List<Vector3>()
            {
                new Vector3(1,1,1),
                new Vector3(2,2,2),
                new Vector3(3,3,3),
                new Vector3(4,4,4),
                new Vector3(5,5,5)
            };

            var timeSeriesAnalysis = new TimeSeriesAnalysisFFT(vect3List);

            var autocorr = timeSeriesAnalysis.GetAutoCorrelationPoints(10);

            IList<double> tausList = new List<double>(autocorr.XData);
            IList<double> autocorrList = new List<double>(autocorr.YData);

            Assert.AreEqual(5, tausList.Count);
            Assert.AreEqual(5, autocorrList.Count);

            Assert.AreEqual(1.0, autocorrList[0]);
            Assert.AreEqual(0.90909090909090906, autocorrList[1]);
            Assert.AreEqual(0.78787878787878785, autocorrList[2]);
            Assert.AreEqual(0.63636363636363635, autocorrList[3]);
            Assert.AreEqual(0.45454545454545453, autocorrList[4]);
        }
    }
}


Unit Test Output:
Test Name:  GetAutoCorrelationPointsTestMethod
Test FullName:  MyNameSpace____unit_test.TimeSeriesAnalysisFFT____unit_test.GetAutoCorrelationPointsTestMethod
Test Source:    C:\git\\TimeSeriesAnalysisFFT_____unit_test.cs : line 46
Test Outcome:   Failed
Test Duration:  0:00:00.0088174

Result StackTrace:  at MyNameSpace____unit_test.TimeSeriesAnalysisFFT____unit_test.GetAutoCorrelationPointsTestMethod() in C:\git\\TimeSeriesAnalysisFFT_____unit_test.cs:line 68
Result Message: Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<0.909090909090909>. Actual:<0.400000005960464>.
Result StandardOutput:  
Normalization factor: 1
Lag must be between 0 and 4, and the list cannot be empty.


Test Name:  GetAutoCorrelationTestMethod
Test FullName:  MyNameSpace____unit_test.TimeSeriesAnalysisFFT____unit_test.GetAutoCorrelationTestMethod
Test Source:    C:\git\\TimeSeriesAnalysisFFT_____unit_test.cs : line 19
Test Outcome:   Failed
Test Duration:  0:00:00.24544

Result StackTrace:  at MyNameSpace____unit_test.TimeSeriesAnalysisFFT____unit_test.GetAutoCorrelationTestMethod() in C:\git\\TimeSeriesAnalysisFFT_____unit_test.cs:line 38
Result Message: Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<33>. Actual:<1>.



What am I doing wrong?

You have code that works, and code that does the same but doesn’t work. You have a debugger, just step through both codes using two instances of VS until you see what’s different.

@stuartd, This is not about debugging. Probably, something is wrong with my formula.

You are doing equality comparisons with floating point? That’s a bad idea, there are rounding errors, the more complex the computations, the bigger those errors. If the tests fail with significant differences to your expected results, please show us which values are different and by how much, and how you determined those expected values.

^^ I know of FluentAssertions Lib that it gives you convenient Assertion methods to account for inherent floating point issues. They would allow you to specify an allowed error margin that is expected. It doesn't even provide exact equality methods for floating point.

The comments so far deal with problems of comparing floating point numbers exactly. But there is much more wrong with your FFT autocorrelation implementation than that.
It is likely that the FFT method will have additional rounding errors when compared to the direct method which with your test data which is almost entirely exact integer arithmetic that fits in the mantissa of double FP numbers. Only the final division has any intrinsic rounding error.
The FFT kernel will have used internally sin(pi/5) and (cos(pi/5) (or sin(pi/10)^2) both of which come with +/- 0.5 ULP random error. Taking the modulus roughly doubles that error and the inverse FFT adds some more so you will be lucky to get better than 3ULP. Comparing for target != 0 abs(result/target)-1 < 1e-15 should be easily achievable - tighter bounds may be possible once you have it working.
To have any reasonable expectation of getting the same answer as the original slow method you have to ask the same question of the FFT version of the code.
The original autocorrelation code computes the autocorrelation with lag m of the isolated ramp waveform that you supplied. Implicitly it looks like
... 0 0 0 1 2 3 4 5 0 0 0 ...

At lag 0: 1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + 4^2 + 5^2 = 55
At lag 1: 0.1 + 1.2 + 2.3 + 3.4 + 4.5 + 5.0 = 40

etc.
The fundamental problem with your FFT code is that you haven't zero padded the data so that it can compute the same autocorrelation function as above. This is discussed in most treatments of the FFT for computing autocorrelations Numerical Recipes #13.2 p 648 is as good as any and online. Short answer is that you must pad the raw dataset with sufficient zeroes that it can accommodate the maximum lag you want to compute.
IOW the basic FFT when handed the array 1 2 3 4 5 computes the result of tiling that function nose to tail periodically onto the x axis.
... 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5...

This has the same zero lag component as before but lag 1 is now on cyclic boundary conditions:
5.1 + 1.2 + 2.3 + 3.4 + 4.5 = 45

Edge effects when the implicit periodicity of the FFT is allowed to affect the final result require that you must zero pad your data in this application. So to be able to compute the same function as the classical slow method you have to zero pad the dataset to twice its original length.
... 1 2 3 4 5 0 0 0 0 0 ...
Then for some strange reason you subtracted the mean from the FFT waveform (this is not necessary and makes things even more wrong) leaving:
-2 -1 0 1 2

Lag 0 gives: 2^2 + 1^2 + 1^2 + 2^2 = 10
Lag 1 gives: -2*(-1) -1*0 + 0*1 + 1*2 = 4

In more general terms fault finding is a lot easier when you display the answer that the failing algorithm has computed rather than just saying it failed this (unreasonable) unit test. The unit test is even more unreasonable than I first thought - the FFT is only working in 32 bit reals so 6 sig fig correct is the most this code can produce.
This is my untested version of AutoCorr with zero padding modified from the OP's original sourcecode. I don't do C# so I have no way to test it. It may need adjusting even to compile.
    public double AutoCorr(int lag)
    {
        int n = _count;

        if (n == 0 || lag >= n || lag < 0)
            throw new ArgumentException($"Lag must be between 0 and {n - 1}, and the list cannot be empty.");

        // Using FFT to compute autocorrelation
        var realValues = _source.Select(v => v.X).ToArray();

        var complexValues = new Complex32[2*n]; // array length doubled
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            complexValues[i] = new Complex32((float)realValues[i], 0);
            complexValues[n+i] = new Complex32(0, 0);  // zero padding added
        }
        // debug print input values here

        // Forward FFT
        Fourier.Forward(complexValues, FourierOptions.Matlab);

        // Compute power spectrum (magnitude squared)
        for (int i = 0; i < 2*n; i++) // twice as many values now
        {
            complexValues[i] = complexValues[i] * Complex32.Conjugate(complexValues[i]);
        }
        // debug print intermediate values here

        // Inverse FFT to get the autocorrelation
        Fourier.Inverse(complexValues, FourierOptions.Matlab);

        // debug print output values here

        // Extract the real part and normalize by number of samples
        var autocorr = complexValues.Select(c => c.Real / n).ToArray();

        // Return the normalized value for the given lag
        double variance = realValues.Sum(x => x * x) / n;

        if (variance == 0)
            return 0;

        return autocorr[lag] / variance;
    }

One other major defect of the "fast" FFT code is that you are recomputing the FFT every time for each autocorrelation coefficient. The whole point of the FFT method is that you can do it once at cost N.log(N) and then read the entire array of autocorrelation results without any further computation.
As an aside you have also made the code more difficult to check and test by choosing a radix-5 FFT. Radix-2 FFT code is simpler and ubiquitous.

I added the unit-test output.

@user366312 I recognise that value of 0.4 - it is the result of erroneously subtracting the mean from your data before the forward FFT step. Also I noticed that the FFT is only real32 precision so it is completely impossible for it to pass your unit tests. The FFT version will get around 6 significant digits right if you are lucky. I will edit my answer to include sample replacement code that implements what I described but please bear in mind I don't use C# and can't test it so it may need tweaking just to compile. Please add some print statements into the code where indicated.
